# RPI Pico build problem - ld.exe: Binary info must be in first 256 bytes of the binary (subproject issue)

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

While trying to build project on Code studio using Pico SDK i'm getting failed build with following log message :

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\Raspberry Pi\Pico SDK v1.5.1\cmake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/_svn/compass/AVR/AMPER_BATERIA_PICO/build --config Debug --target all --
[build] [1/2  50% :: 0.133] Building C object GENET_CORE_PICO/CMakeFiles/GENET_CORE.dir/GENet_Core.c.obj
[build] [2/2 100% :: 0.293] Linking CXX executable Amper_Bateria.elf
[build] FAILED: Amper_Bateria.elf 
[...a lot of build output here...]    
[build] C:/Program Files/Raspberry Pi/Pico SDK v1.5.1/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_base/include/hardware/address_mapped.h:122: multiple definition of `adc_init'; GENET_CORE_PICO/CMakeFiles/GENET_CORE.dir/C_/Program_Files/Raspberry_Pi/Pico_SDK_v1.5.1/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_adc/adc.c.obj:C:/Program Files/Raspberry Pi/Pico SDK v1.5.1/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_base/include/hardware/address_mapped.h:122: first defined here
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\Raspberry Pi\Pico SDK v1.5.1\cmake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build d:/_svn/compass/AVR/AMPER_BATERIA_PICO/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
[build] c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Binary info must be in first 256 bytes of the binary
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.569
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

What could be the problem ? My Main project CMakeLists :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
project(Amper_Bateria C CXX ASM)
set(srcDir D:/_svn/compass/AVR/AMPER_BATERIA_PICO)
add_subdirectory(GENET_CORE_PICO)
pico_sdk_init()
set(SOURCES userland.c userland.h)
add_executable(Amper_Bateria ${SOURCES})
target_link_directories(Amper_Bateria PRIVATE ${coreDir})
pico_add_extra_outputs(Amper_Bateria)
target_include_directories(Amper_Bateria PRIVATE GENET_CORE_PICO)
target_link_directories(Amper_Bateria PRIVATE GENET_CORE_PICO)
target_link_libraries(Amper_Bateria PRIVATE GENET_CORE pico_stdlib hardware_adc pico_multicore hardware_timer)
```

subproject file :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)
project(GENET_CORE C CXX ASM)
pico_sdk_init()
add_library(GENET_CORE 
OBJECT GENet_Core.c GENet_Core.h GENet_ISR_LIB.c GENet_ISR_LIB.h ds18b20_TIMER_DRIVER.c ds18b20_TIMER_DRIVER.h crc8_16.c checksum.h
)
target_link_libraries(GENET_CORE pico_stdlib hardware_adc)
```

this happens only when i try to build this code with subfolder. Putting everything into single folder works fine.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with STM32 header needed for binaries loaded by ROM code as written on this page ? https://wiki.stmicroelectronics.cn/stm32mpu/index.php?title=STM32_header_for_binary_files&oldid=67051 
Why linker is not taking care of this ? I'm not sure where to search for answers, as I'm not super experienced in this architecture. (previously worked on ATMega chips with atmel studio)